# How i can print on client side without browser?

Tags: java, printing

I am developing a web application on Java for the sale of tickets on stadium.

The problem is that need to implement printing of tickets for the client printer, but the application is trying to find a printer on the server.

Unacceptable that the ticket was displayed in the browser.

Necessary that it be done automatically by pressing the button.

How to solve this problem? Help please, who knows how to implement it.

For detecting printer I use PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); But this search printers on the server where the application is deployed, rather than on client machine.

Comment: show us some codes man

Comment: Is this not a web application? Is it a desktop one? Look into [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) - you can generate and export PDF files, that the client can afterwards print

Comment: please add some code, will help to figure out your problem.

Comment: You should be able to print decent tickets as HTML pages, without PDF files. The print button in your page can execute window.print() to access the user's printer via Javascript; building a special "printable ticket" page with text and server-generated images should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If your objective is to print on client printer using printerjob and java graphics libary then you need to invoke servlet-applet communication.
  Separate printing code/module in jar from your application and call it client side through applet. Applet will download your jar and will print at client location.

Other way, generate ticket in web-page using html/jsp, call windows.print using javascript. When user will click print then it will print on client location.

Comment: If we are using the first approach, is there an alternate of applet as Java applets are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You basically cannot do this in general on browsers, however you ca ask the browser to print a page that you create from javascript. Precisely how this is implemented depends on the browser.

So in essence you have to output a HTML file that includes javascript to instruct the browser to print the contents (probably using window.print() in javascript)

Comment: I can not use window.print(). Just I have printer Zebra and special format ticket with empty places. I have to send to the printer objects and shape, according to which they should be printed. ie, if I need to print 3 tickets, I send 3 objects and the printer must print 3 pages.

Comment: This truly is the ONLY way. Running in a browser your code can't just reach out and find a zebra printer on a usb port and write to it - the code is sandboxed against this type of access.

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea... I will try to develop client application and install it to client machine. And I will link the applications with help JMS. Ie, web-app sent tickets_id to machine and my client-app print this tickets.

Comment: I think that's not worth it.. But I'm egar to listen what you do back in the future..

Comment: As far as I remember we decided to use applets. It was the easiest solution.